# Axios AWS Cognito Error; 405 Method Not allowed

Tags: node.js, cloud, amazon-cognito

I am AWS Cognito's hosted UI with an Express backend. I am trying to use the authorization code grant to get the proper tokens. Each time I make a request I get 405: Method not allowed. I've double checked my credentials, they are correct, my region is correct, I am grabbing the code from the url, the encoded authorization is being encoded properly. I don't know why I get the error, previous solutions indicate something wrong with the redirect url, but I've tried it with and without the /, I've tried swapping some of the credentials to the header, and swapping some to the body. Assistance would be greatly appreciated!
Cognito settings : https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AZyc.jpg

```
let code= req.query.code;

if(code== undefined || code === null)
{

    next();
    return;

}

let encodedAuth ="Basic "+base64encode(process.env.COGNITO_APP_CLIENT+":"+process.env.COGNITO_APP_CLIENT_SECRET);

await axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'https://MYDOMAIN.auth.us-east-2.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token',
    header: { Content_Type: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            Authorization:encodedAuth},
    data:{
        
        grant_type:'authorization_code',
        code:code,
        client_id:process.env.COGNITO_APP_CLIENT,
        redirect_uri:'http://localhost:8080/'
     }
})
.then(function(err,value){
    console.log("Here!");
})
.catch(function(err,value){
    console.log("Error while logging in!");
    console.log(err);
})
```

Comment: Let's try with the header like: ``headers: {'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Authorization': encodedAuth
  }``

Comment: I did a copy and paste, did not work. I also tried swapping the dash to an underscore, and it did not work.